# Change Typescript Variable DataType After Initialisation using Or

Tags: typescript

Consider this function,

```
sampleFunction(val :string | Node){
if(typeof(val) === 'string'){
  val = this.getNode(val) as Node;
 }

const innerFunction = () => {
    ...
    still the type of val is string | Node
    ...
}
}
```

How to convert the type from string | Node to just Node ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of val is still `string | Node`, even though you assigned a `Node` to it since val can contain `string` or `Node` . Assign the value to a new const (`nodeVal` perhaps) and you will be sorted.

Comment: Is there any other way without creating a variable ?

Comment: You can use an if block for `Node` like you did for `string`. I also wonder if you add another if block that says `if(typeof(val) === 'string') return;` If the compiler will know everything after that is Node